# Char(39) in my sql doesnt print any stuff?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT top 20 p.ID'
            + CHAR(10) +' from dbo.Prospects P WITH (NOLOCK)'
            + CHAR(10) +' where p.State =ISNULL('+ CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + @State + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)+','+'p.State)'

print (@sSql)
```

When I try to print the above statement it doesn't give back any o/p ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and it does print output if `@State` is set to a value.  I suspect it is `NULL`, which is why you aren't seeing anything.

Note that you are trying to construct a SQL string that returns a value when `p.State` is `NULL`, but when concatenating the string, if `@State` is `NULL`, the result of the concatenation becomes `NULL`.

You can try testing `@State` at the time you construct the sql statement instead:

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT top 20 p.ID'
            + CHAR(10) +' from dbo.Prospects P WITH (NOLOCK)'
            + CHAR(10) +' where p.State = ' + ISNULL('''' + @State + '''', 'p.State')
```

Comment: Yes because it is present within a ISNULL function,but did you just set a value to one and see if it prints

Comment: Correct, I declare `@State` with a value and it printed output.

Comment: So just for printing I am setting a value,when I use the SP_EXECUTESQL I will be removing the set value, will it still work

Comment: @user3442679 No, the statement will be null when you try to execute it.  You could try to pass it in as an embedded parameter or construct the statement based on the value of `@State` (see my edits).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare @sSQL as whatever type it is. Also in that code you posted, @State is neither declared, nor set.

For example:

```
DECLARE @sSQL as varchar
```